# Queries in the preliminaries of Runge's theorem(Complex Analysis).

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Reference:[Function of one comlex variable by J.B Conway](https://emineter.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/conway-functions-of-one-complex-variable-2ed-1978lt167s.pdf).

> Let $K$ be a compact subset of the region $G$,then there  are straight
>   lines $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\ldots,\gamma_n$ in $G-K $ such that  for every
>   function $f$ in $H(G)$,$$\sum _{k=1}^n
>  \int_{\gamma_k}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw$$
>
> $\forall z\in K$.The line segments form a finite number of closed
>   polygons.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've two minor queries-

$1.$How $\phi (w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}$ happened before equation(1.3)?

$2.$How,If $z \notin R_j$,then $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial R_j}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw=0$ after equation (1.3)?